# how to separate the value from a key value pair in MongoDB Java,add up the values

Tags: java, mongodb

The below code projects only one field with the key value pair, the issue is how to separate the value and add them and avg it out.

```
private static void selectAllRecordByRecordNumber(DBCollection collection) {
    BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBObject whereQuery1 = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBObject whereQuery2 = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("pr", 1);
    fields.put("_id", 0);
    int TotalPseudorange=0;
    whereQuery.put("st", 17);
    whereQuery2.put("pr",whereQuery);
    whereQuery1.put("pr",new BasicDBObject("st",17));
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(whereQuery,fields);
    TotalPseudorange = TotalPseudorange + cursor.count();
    int count=cursor.count();
    int index_count=0;
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }
    System.out.println("The calculation is complete & Done");
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Comment: The above code separates a single field with a key value pair but i want to separate just the values and add them up.

Comment: And what have you tried to solve this?

Comment: i used tokenizer, but the same did not give me the results

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `.get()` method in the iterated object:

```
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(cursor.next().get("pr"));
}
```

Then you can replace the above with the following to get the average in java8-fashion.

```
    StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(cursor,
            Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
            .mapToDouble(item -> ((Number)item.get("pr")).doubleValue() )
            .summaryStatistics()
            .getAverage();
```

Note: I am not exactly sure what the return type of `get` will be but I think it could also be safe to directly cast to double.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: @Marinos An Can you please explain the code, i am unable to use it.

Comment: Can you provide the  output of  `System.out.println(cursor.next())`?

Comment: @Marinos An  { "pr" : 2.8215348146E7}

{ "pr" : 2.2931185061E7}

{ "pr" : 2.7102435441E7}

{ "pr" : 2.3933516976E7}

{ "pr" : 2.8215354562E7}

{ "pr" : 2.2930403451E7}

{ "pr" : 2.7101372119E7}

{ "pr" : 2.3933408522E7}

{ "pr" : 2.8215360943E7}

{ "pr" : 2.2929621863E7}

{ "pr" : 2.7100309144E7}

{ "pr" : 2.3933299949E7}

{ "pr" : 2.8215367327E7}

{ "pr" : 2.2928840287E7}

Comment: @MarinosAn The above is the output that i am currently getting. I want to add only the values and present it.

Comment: @MarinosAn how do i get to display the output in this replacement?StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(cursor,
            Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
            .mapToDouble(item -> ((Number)item.get("pr")).doubleValue() )
            .summaryStatistics()
            .getAverage();

Comment: @MarinoAn how do i store it in a variable?double exam = StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(cursor, Spliterator.ORDERED), false) .mapToDouble(item -> ((Number)item.get("pr")).doubleValue() ) .summaryStatistics() .getAverage();  System.out.println(exam.getAverage()); i tried it in this way but it did not work.

Comment: Please be more descriptive. "It didn't work" is too broad.

Comment: @MarinosAn it's giving me an error saying, cannot invoke getAverage() on the prmitive type double, at the line when i am trying to print out the average.